bash_completion script crashes bash
I moved alias, env var and completion declarations out of .bashrc and into separate files:

.bash_env
.bash_aliases
.bash_completion

and imported them inside .bashrc
if [ -f ~/.bash_env ]; then
    . ~/.bash_env
fi

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

if [ -f ~/.bash_completion ]; then
    . ~/.bash_completion
fi

But now on launching bash hangs until a text pop saying:

Warning: Program '/bin/bash' crashed.

I've identified that it's the sourcing of .bash_completion that cause the crash, more specifically those lines that were present in the default .bashrc:
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

Somehow, sourcing /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion inside .bash_completion causes a crash

It turns out that /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion itself tries to import ~/.bash_completion and I wasn't aware of that.
So it can be solved by either naming .bash_completion differently or sourcing /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion and letting it import ~/.bash_completion.
